# Getting a warning called Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, react-state

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Rando extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // want to use props insode brackets if we want to use props inside the constructor
        this.state = { num: 0, color: 'purple' };
        this.makeTimer();
    }

    makeTimer() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxNum);

            this.setState({ num: rand });
        }, 10);
    }
    render() {
        console.log('changing');
        return (
            <div className=''>
                <h1>{this.state.num}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rando;
```

I'm getting a warning that looks like this

index.js:1 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Rando component.

I'm a beginner, I have no idea what's causing this. please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you call a function in your `constructor`

Comment: @bamtheboozle because `constructor` is the first thing which is called and `componentDidMount` is the last one (during mounting phase). As the warning says, the component is not yet mounted and you're calling `setState`, so this is the reason why this function shouldn't be called inside a `constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timer function gets executed even before the component gets mounted. Try putting the code inside `componentDidMount` hook. Also don't forget to clear the interval id inside `componentWillUnmount`.

Sandbox link for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-sybv0?file=/src/index.js

**Modified Snippet**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Rando extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = { num: 0, color: 'purple' };
        this.timer = null;
    }

     componentDidMount() {
        this.makeTimer();
     }
   
     componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
     }

    makeTimer = () => {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxNum);
            this.setState({ num: rand });
        }, 10);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.num}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rando;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `this.makeTimer();` on `componentDidMount()` instead of `constructor`

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.makeTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Rando extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // want to use props insode brackets if we want to use props inside the constructor
        this.state = { num: 0, color: 'purple' };
        this.makeTimer((data) => {
          this.setState(data);
        });
    }

    makeTimer(cb) {
        setInterval(() => {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxNum);

            
            cb({ num: rand })
        }, 10);
    }
    render() {
        console.log('changing');
        return (
            <div className=''>
                <h1>{this.state.num}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rando;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Rando extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // want to use props insode brackets if we want to use props inside the constructor
        this.state = { num: 0, color: 'purple' };
    }

    makeTimer() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxNum);

            this.setState({ num: rand });
        }, 10);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
    this.makeTimer();
    }

    render() {
        console.log('changing');
        return (
            <div className=''>
                <h1>{this.state.num}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rando;
```